# std::set_difference on map and a vector throws conversion errors

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector, stdmap, set-difference

The following code should compute the difference of a map and a vector

```
std::map<int, int> cursorMap;
QVector<User> userList;
...
std::vector<int> offlineUserIds{};
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
it = std::set_difference(cursorMap.begin(), cursorMap.end(), userList.begin(), userList.end(), offlineUserIds.begin(),
[](const std::pair<int, int> &e, const User &u){ return u.getId() == e.first; });
```

before invoking `set_difference`, `userList` is converted to a `std::vector` and sorted. The problem is that it gaves me the following errors:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::pair<const int, int>' to 'int' in assignment
...
error: no match for call to '(TextEditor::updateCursorMap(QVector<User>)::<lambda(const std::pair<int, int>&, const User&)>) (User&, std::pair<const int, int>&)'
         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
...
note: candidate: 'TextEditor::updateCursorMap(QVector<User>)::<lambda(const std::pair<int, int>&, const User&)>'
...
     it = std::set_difference(cursorMap.begin(), cursorMap.end(), userList.begin(), userList.end(), offlineUserIds.begin(), [](const std::pair<int, int> &e, const User &u){ return u.getId() == e.first; });
...
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'User' to 'const std::pair<int, int>&'
```

EDIT:

I tried the following code

```
std::map<int, int> cursorMap;
QVector<User> userList;
...
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> offlineUserIds{};
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator it;
it = std::set_difference(cursorMap.begin(), cursorMap.end(), userList.begin(), userList.end(), offlineUserIds.begin(), [](const std::pair<int, int> &e, const User &u){ return e.first < u.getId(); });
```

but now it gives me

```
note: candidate: 'TextEditor::updateCursorMap(QVector<User>)::<lambda(const std::pair<int, int>&, const User&)>'
     it = std::set_difference(cursorMap.begin(), cursorMap.end(), userList.begin(), userList.end(), offlineUserIds.begin(), [](const std::pair<int, int> &e, const User &u){ return e.first < u.getId(); });
...
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'User' to 'const std::pair<int, int>&'
```

EDIT2:

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

class User {
    int id;
public:
    int getId() const { return id; }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<User> newUserList{};
    std::map<int, int> cursorMap{};
    std::vector<User> userList = std::vector(newUserList.begin(), newUserList.end());
    std::sort(userList.begin(), userList.end(), [](const User &u1, const User &u2) { return u1.getId() < u2.getId(); });

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> offlineUserIds{};
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator it;
    it = std::set_difference(cursorMap.begin(), cursorMap.end(), userList.begin(), userList.end(), offlineUserIds.begin(), [](std::pair<int, int> e, User u){ return e.first < u.getId(); });

    return 0;
}
```

build output

```
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from D:\asant\workspace\CLionProjects\untitled\main.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<User*, std::vector<User> >; _Iterator2 = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(std::pair<int, int>, User)>]':
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5343:17:   required from '_OutputIterator std::__set_difference(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _InputIterator2, _OutputIterator, _Compare) [with _InputIterator1 = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >; _InputIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<User*, std::vector<User> >; _OutputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(std::pair<int, int>, User)> >]'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5447:46:   required from '_OIter std::set_difference(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _IIter2, _OIter, _Compare) [with _IIter1 = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >; _IIter2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<User*, std::vector<User> >; _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(std::pair<int, int>, User)>]'
D:\asant\workspace\CLionProjects\untitled\main.cpp:21:188:   required from here
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:143:18: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(std::pair<int, int>, User)>) (User&, std::pair<const int, int>&)'
         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:143:18: note: candidate: 'bool (*)(std::pair<int, int>, User)' <conversion>
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:143:18: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 3 provided
D:\asant\workspace\CLionProjects\untitled\main.cpp:21:156: note: candidate: 'main()::<lambda(std::pair<int, int>, User)>'
     it = std::set_difference(cursorMap.begin(), cursorMap.end(), userList.begin(), userList.end(), offlineUserIds.begin(), [](std::pair<int, int> e, User u){ return e.first < u.getId(); });
                                                                                                                                                            ^
D:\asant\workspace\CLionProjects\untitled\main.cpp:21:156: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'User' to 'std::pair<int, int>'
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\build.make:82: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:137: untitled] Error 2
```

Comment: please include  [mcve] and the complete error message in the question

Comment: What is meaning of second parameter of map?

Comment: position of a user cursor inside a document

Comment: Do you have C++ 20 or Range v3? This can actually be done decently and efficiently with it.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, there's another problem. Since `offlineUserIds` is an **empty vector** you can't use `offlineUserIds.begin()` as the output destination for the algorithm. That won't grow the container. To add elements to a container the destination needs to be something like `std::back_inserter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reason that is not known to me:

> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that objects of types InputIt1
> and InputIt2 can be dereferenced and **then implicitly converted to both
> Type1 and Type2**

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference). Last sentence under Parameters -> comp. Highlighted by me.

Comment: Not applicable here.

Comment: So we should conclude that we cannot apply set_difference to two different types of container I guess

Comment: @AntonioSantoro not true but in your particular case it not possible because you can't make std::pair be convertible to its key. Only way to set_difference is rescind map use. Or write own algorithm. Also you might want to have own class for userId instead of using int, for type safety and possible implicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

The value type of the template class `std::map` is defined like

```
typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type;
```

However the value type of the class `std::vector<int>` is `int`.

You can not assign an object of the typs `std::pair` to an object of the type `int`.

So the compiler issues an error.

Moreover the comparison function can be called with any order of the passed arguments. So again the compiler can issue an error that invalid arguments are used because the types of parameters are different and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another..

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting why you are saying that the type of the parameters of the `comp` are wrong, they seems correct to me

Comment: @AntonioSantoro See their declarations in the lambda const std::pair<int, int> &e, const User &u

Comment: `*cursorMap.begin()` returns a `std::pair<int,int>` while `*userList.begin()` returns a `User`, even changing the `comp` signature to `[](std::pair<int, int> e, User u)` gives this error: `note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'User' to 'std::pair<int, int>'`

Comment: @AntonioSantoro As I said the arguments can be passed to the lambda in any order.

Comment: I removed the const qualifier, I'm not referring to their order

Comment: @AntonioSantoro It does not matter. The first parameter has the type std::pair while the second parameter has the type User and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.  That is the algorithm can pass as the first argument an object of the type User and the second argument as an object of the type std::pair that is in the reverse order relative to teh declared parameters.

Comment: @AntonioSantoro To make it clear the comparison function can be called for example like if ( cmp( a, b ) ) { /*do something*/ } else if ( !cmp( b, a ) ) { /*do somethings*/ }

Answer (score 1):

You may want either roll own difference function or provide User with conversion operator which would allow set_difference to compare pair and User.

set_difference requires mutual conversion and ability to insert Type1 to output sequence. With use of `std::map` mutual conversion is not possible because conversion operator must be member of `std::pair` in that case.

Comment: so the `comp` lambda function at the end of `set_difference` is not enough?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro that function is used to exclude elements. See docs and implementation example at cppreference.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator **cmp** for set_difference is **LessCompare** and the equivalence will be checked with
something like:

```
 pair<int, int> e == User u <==> !(e < u) && !(u < e) <==> !cmp(e,u) && !cmp(u,e)
```

This will work only if **e** and **u** are convertible to each other, which is not the case.

Comment: I've added a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score -1):

I believe your lambda is taking parameters in the wrong order. Try the one below.

```
[](const User &u, const std::pair<int, int> &e){ return u.getId() == e.first; });
```

Comment: That;s not enough, set_difference compares elements of two sets, usin ==, > , etc.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie It compares two sequences, nothing about sets.

Comment: @Badar they have to be ordered sequences for set_difference to work  and map is an ordered unique, so they are sets by property, custom implementation could use that

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie An ordered sequence is vastly different from a set. You can sort two vectors and pass them to set_difference() and it will return correct result. Neither would be a set or map in that case.

Comment: @TanveerBadar you're mixing up type "std::set" and set as a term. Which would a presumably sorted sequence of unique elements, nothing less , nothing more, two sequences, one of which contains no elements  other doesn't, are equal.  `set_difference`, `set_symmetric_difference` and such  are  named so because they act on sequences on assumptions they have certain restrictions on par with set theory.